# A tale of two stochastic processes

Tags: probability

For discrete time Markov Chains, I have seen very exact formulas that can be used to calculate the "expected time of absorption" and the "probability distribution of absorption times". That is, provided some initial conditions, how long will it take for the Markov Chain to first reach a certain state?

But I always wondered - can this concept be extended to some arbitrary sequence of states? For example: If a Stochastic Process moves +1 with prob=0.5 and -1 with prob=-0.5 ... if this Stochastic Process starts at position=5

- Situation 1: What is the expected time at which the process will first reach position = 0?
- Situation 2:  What is the expected time at which the process will first reach position= 0 AFTER having gone to position=10 at least once?

I am not sure how to analyze these questions mathematically so I made simulations (R) to study the expected absorption times and the (sampling) distributions of absorption times:

```
# the simulations can take a long time to run, I interrupted them

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

n_sims <- 100
times_to_end_0 <- numeric(n_sims)
times_to_end_0_after_10 <- numeric(n_sims)
paths_0 <- vector("list", n_sims)
paths_0_after_10 <- vector("list", n_sims)

for (i in 1:n_sims) {
    print(paste("Running simulation", i, "for situation 1..."))
    y <- 5
    time <- 0
    path_0 <- c(y)

    while(y > 0) {
        step <- sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
        y <- y + step
        path_0 <- c(path_0, y)
        time <- time + 1

        if (y == 0) {
            times_to_end_0[i] <- time
            paths_0[[i]] <- data.frame(time = 1:length(path_0), y = path_0, sim = i)
            break
        }
    }

    print(paste("Running simulation", i, "for situation 2..."))
    y <- 5
    time <- 0
    reached_10 <- FALSE
    path_0_after_10 <- c(y)

    while(y > 0 || !reached_10) {
        step <- sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
        y <- y + step
        path_0_after_10 <- c(path_0_after_10, y)
        time <- time + 1

        if (y == 10) {
            reached_10 <- TRUE
        }

        if (y == 0 && reached_10) {
            times_to_end_0_after_10[i] <- time
            paths_0_after_10[[i]] <- data.frame(time = 1:length(path_0_after_10), y = path_0_after_10, sim = i)
            break
        }
    }
}

df1 <- data.frame(time = times_to_end_0)
df2 <- data.frame(time = times_to_end_0_after_10[times_to_end_0_after_10 > 0])

mean1 <- mean(log(df1$time))
mean2 <- mean(log(df2$time))

p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = log(time))) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = exp(mean1)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
    labs(title = paste("Density of Times to Reach 0 - Mean Time:", round(exp(mean1), 2)), x = "Time", y = "Density") + theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = log(time))) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = exp(mean2)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
    labs(title = paste("Density of Times to Reach 0 After Reaching 10 - Mean Time:", round(exp(mean2), 2)), x = "Time", y = "Density") + theme_bw() 

plot_df_0 <- do.call(rbind, paths_0)

p3 <- ggplot(plot_df_0, aes(x = log(time), y = y, group = sim)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = "Paths of First Simulation", x = "Time", y = "Y") +
    theme_bw()

plot_df_0_after_10 <- do.call(rbind, paths_0_after_10)

p4 <- ggplot(plot_df_0_after_10, aes(x = log(time), y = y, group = sim)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = "Paths of Second Simulation", x = "Time", y = "Y") +
    theme_bw()

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

As expected, Situation 2 is taking a much longer time than Situation 1 as it can go "way out of bounds" before getting back on track in the direction of 0

**My Question:** Are there some mathematical formulas we can use to study the expected absorption time and distribution of absorption time for Situation 2? Is this where the principle of reflection would be used?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, but what does this have to do with "two brownian motions"? And how is the process you described not a discrete time process? If it's continuous time, what does it mean to move $+1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$?

Comment: This looks like a discrete time Markov chain that is a random walk on the integers. The expected time to reach 0, given we start at some state $n \in\{1, 2, 3,...\}$, is $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

To help with finding references: your stochastic process is a **simple symmetric random walk** starting at 5. For convenience I will instead take the process to start at zero, and rephrase your two questions as

1. What is the expected time to reach position $-5$?
2. What is the expected time to reach position $-5$ after having gone to position $5$ at least once?

---

For the first question, the expected time is infinite. We can formulate your process as $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ where each $X_i$ independently takes values $\pm 1$ with equal probability; note that $S_n$ is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)).
Let $\tau = \inf\{n : S_n = -5\}$ denote the first time the process hits $-5$; $\tau$ is a [stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time). If $E[\tau]< \infty$, then the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) would imply $E[S_\tau]=0$. But by definition $S_\tau = -5$, which is a contradiction.

By extension, the expected number of steps to reach position $5$ is also infinite, so the expectation in your second question is also infinite.

---

Aside: a slightly different question might be "what is the expected time to hit either $-5$ or $5$?" This stopping time $\tau' = \inf\{n : S_n \in \{-5, 5\}\}$ has a finite expectation. For this, the trick is to use the fact that [$S_n^2-n$ is a martingale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382269/how-to-prove-s-n2-n-is-still-a-martingale). Then the optional stopping theorem implies $E[S^2_{\tau'} - \tau'] = 0$, so $E[\tau'] = E[S_{\tau'}^2] = 5^2$.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I have seen this type of analysis presented before (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085399/expectation-of-hitting-time-for-simple-symmetric-random-walk) and could never quite understand it. I have seen videos like this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH2kATv49rc) which show that a 1D and 2D random walk are guaranteed to return to return to its origin (i.e. probability=1) yet the time is infinite?